# Get google calendar events full details including remainder and Attendees

Tags: java, android, calendar

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), 
               new String[]{"_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"}, 
              null, null, null);
```

I am using the above code for get the calendar events. I want more details about the event like remainder, Attendees.